# 'Final_Project.Member' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
      while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                aMember = new Member(dbReader["FirstName"].ToString(),                 dbReader["LastName"].ToString());
                this.lstbxNames.Items.Add(aMember);

            }
            dbReader.Close();
            dbConn.Close();
        }



   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

 namespace Final_Project
{
     class Member
     {
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string currentbalance;

    public Member()
    {

    }

    public Member(string lname)
    {
        string LastName = lname;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }

    public string CurrentBalance
    {
        get { return currentbalance; }
        set { currentbalance = value; }
    }
}
```

}

I am not sure how to fix this error. I have created a class for 'Member' but I am still getting the error that says it does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments. I have added the first part of the code that has the error and the class I created that should have made it work.

Comment: you are passing two parameters to **Member** constructor, while you don't have any constructor defined in Member class which takes 2

Comment: change your existing constructor :``public Member(string lname)
    {
        string LastName = lname;
    }`` to:``public Member(string fname,string lname)
    {
        string LastName = lname;
    }``

Answer (score 0):

```
aMember = new Member(dbReader["FirstName"].ToString(), dbReader["LastName"].ToString());
```

so lets pretend those values end up looking like this

```
aMember = new Member("Bill","Gates");
```

so rather than a comma, maybe you need to join those fields together?? 
or change your creation so you send it first and surname, and set both fields as you have option for both in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new constructor to let you pass in first name and last name, then set your properties in it. Currently you only have a constructor that accepts one argument that then sets the LastName property.

```
public Member(string lname)
{
    LastName = lname;
}

//New overloaded constructor for lastname and firstname.
public Member(string lname, string fname)
{
    LastName = lname;
    FirstName = fname;
}
```

Modifying a code line you have that is attempting to intialize a new member:

```
aMember = new Member(dbReader["LastName"].ToString(), dbReader["FirstName"].ToString());
```

If you would rather make it firstName, lastName for initialization, you could flip the constructor arguments around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want your Final_Project.Member constructor as

```
 public Member(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    this.firstname = firstName;
    this.lastname = lastName;
}
```

this will work fine.